# Android No Action Bar Glitch

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appbar

I'm just trying to use the no action bar. I don't know why this is failing to import.

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Error states [2015-06-11 22:26:46 - Krowd1] D:\WorkSpace\Krowd1\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Light.NoActionBar'.
[2015-06-11 22:26:46 - Krowd1]

I've tried doing what the posts at stack say to import the V7 support and stuff. But to do that it says access denied? What to do now?

Comment: Celary explain the question

Comment: Do you need app bar am i right

Comment: Yes I do. But for that I have to disable the action bar first? That's what all the videos said. Light.NoActionBar

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    </style>

Comment: That's what I did in my code.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the action bar just type this code in your activity where you want to remove the actionbar.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

Hope its work!

Comment: No! thats android:Theme.Light.NoActionBar can you change like this it really work

Comment: and also you need to extends your activity to AppCompactActivity

Answer (score 0):

Which API are you using?
The one you used will work upto API 9 only
Hence you need to use

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </style>
```

And make sure you've imported appcompat and extended your activity to AppCompactActivity
1.File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "appcompat"

2.Project-> properties->Android. In the section library "Add" and choose "appCompat"